# What to name the X11 version of [dwm]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are 2 types of questions tagged with [dwm](/questions/tagged/dwm):

- [Desktop Window Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for Windows)
- [dynamic window manager](http://dwm.suckless.org) (for X11)

It appears the former is more commonly-used, so I wonder what name to use for the X11 questions? Maybe (the ugly) [x11-dwm](/questions/tagged/x11-dwm)?

Comment: `[suckless-dwm]` would be an appropriate alternative in my opinion.

Comment: Alternatively we could spell both out: `[desktop-window-manager]` and `[dynamic-window-manager]`. I also thought about prefixing the Microsoft one with `windows` or `microsoft`...but that sounds less than ideal.